# Is it safe to grant access to Workbench to any user?

Tags: workbench

Workbench does honor a user's permissions so they cannot do something like set passwords if they do not have that permission, but are there other hazards to granting access to it?

Since it requires API Enabled, are there other capabilities they gain simply from that permission that are also hazardous (e.g. using other API tools to access Salesforce)?

Comment: I wouldn't really extend User's permission if not required. While using Workbench a User will only have access to the data that they are authorized to, but they will definitely get additional resources to browse through and be able to retrieve data from Salesforce. As for *safe*, as long as you have the right data visibility set on the User, it can be considered to be safe, but again I will review if at all my Users need an API access.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do password management from workbench. Click under `Utilites` in the upper right corner. So in addition to that, there are other risks - i.e.they can delete data and purge data (i.e. empty the recyling bin).

Why do they want access? I'd be ok giving them access to a sandbox.

Comment: Mostly thinking about doing it for the convenience (nothing to buy or install) and its Smart Lookup feature. But also just asking here because there's no content elsewhere that addresses this, so figured we should talk about it.

Comment: The Password Management feature only works for those users who can already manage users (I assume that's the underlying permission that is required. And I would expect that delete & purge are also limited by OLS, so nothing that they could not do in Salesforce already (well, not purge easily).